# prometheus is not able to access metrics from localhost

Tags: node.js, docker-compose, prometheus

I have been trying to configure prometheus to show metrics in grafana for my nodejs application. For metrics, I am using prom-client. However, on localhost I get always following error:

```
Get http://localhost:5000/metrics: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:5000: connect: connection refused
```

Moreover, if I use a local tunneling service, such as ngrok, it will be able to read the metrics. What am I missing ? I need to add some special config somewhere ?

This is my prometheus.yml file:

```
global:
    scrape_interval: 5s
    external_labels:
        monitor: 'my-monitor'
scrape_configs:
    - job_name: 'prometheus'
      static_configs:
               - targets: ['localhost:9090']
    - job_name: 'my-app'
      static_configs:
               - targets: ['localhost:5000']
```

I am running the default prometheus image with docker-compose, same for grafana.

Comment: Are you sure your app listens on localhost:5000? Try with 0.0.0.0:5000.

Comment: @radar same output

Comment: Can you post your full docker-compose file? Does the app run in it's own container? Or on the host machine?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because you're using **docker-compose**, therefore `localhost` or `127.0.0.1` won't work in the docker container.

You can replace `localhost` with ***your machine IP*** or use **ngrok** as you did, docker can *resolve* it to your IP.

Thanks for reading :D

Comment: Thanks for answer. I have seen many related issues with this before

Comment: Thanks. Got a lots of pain for this. Finally it worked.

Comment: Yes, I started with `./prometheus --web.listen-address=192.168.0.109:9090`